# How to calculate the sum of numbers divisible by 3 and 5 using lambda's range, map, filter and reduce

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, filter, reduce

I need help with calculating the sum of numbers divisible by 3 or 5 within a given range. So far I've gotten to this;

```
print filter(reduce(map(lambda x, y: x % 3 == 0 or y % 5 == 0, x + y, range(30))))
```

which throws this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#65>", line 1, in <module>
print filter(reduce(map(lambda x, y: x % 3 == 0 or y % 5 == 0, x + y, range(30))))
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I don't think I'm close to finding the solution or even on the right track, so if anyone could point me in the direction that would great, cheers.

Comment: Try breaking that statement into multiple lines and I think you'll see the issue. In other words, start simple and build to your desired result before compressing code into a single line like this.

Comment: Your title says "divisible by 3 and 5" while your body and code indicates you want divisible by 3 or 5. To be clear, which one is it? Do you count numbers divisible only by 3 or only by 5?

Comment: Side-note: `map`, `filter` and `reduce` are typically frowned upon as not Pythonic, with list comprehensions & generator expressions (rather than `map`/`filter`) and explicit accumulator loops (rather than `reduce`) being preferred. They have their place, but if you need to force them into the code (particularly if you need `lambda`s to do it), they're the wrong solution. If this isn't a strict requirement for some illustrative homework assignment, find a better way.

Comment: @ShadowRanger as per the task it requires the sum of numbers divisible by 3 or 5 within a given range (the range in this case being 30). And yeah, I fully understand that but as you noted, it's for illustrative purposes more than anything I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After defining `a` and `b` with `b > a`:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0, range(a, b)))
```

in your case:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0, range(30)))
```

or without `reduce` and `filter`:

```
sum(x for x in range(30) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0)
```

if the range of values is large (not `30`) you could use `xrange` if on python 2 so that it returns a generator instead of a list.

If you really want to also include the `map` function you can use it with the identity function as follows:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0,
                                  map(lambda x: x, range(30))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

`sum([i for i in range(1,100) if i%3==0 and i%5==0])`

Feel free to ask, if you need some explanation :)

Comment: You don't need the brackets (generator / list).

Answer (score 0):

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, filter(lambda x : x % 3 == 0 or x%5 == 0, range(11)), 0)
```

Comment: `sum` isn't one of the allowed tools. `sum(seq)` is just an optimized form of `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, seq, 0)` though, so that's an easy fix. That said, this still won't work; you're massively overcounting the numbers divisible by 3.

Comment: Technically though he didn't say we could use list comprehensions either

Comment: Yeah. The list comprehension is what's causing the massive overcounting here, because you made it effectively a doubly-nested loop (looping `30 ** 2` times, not `30` times).

Comment: Oh, that's a pretty bad mistake! Fixed again... and I checked the output for `range(11)` thanks

Comment: K. Downvote removed; I edited to remove the list comp entirely, since once you fixed up the use of `filter`, the list comp was basically a noop; it took the output of `filter`, and made a new `list` that was identical to what `filter` produced.